# jquery fadeOut function will not work

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

Writing my first piece of code here so bear with my inability. I'm writing a simple one page dreamcatcher app and I'd like the text up top to slowly fade once the page loads. I think I wrote everything correctly but when I load the page the text does not fade.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title>DreamCatcher</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="heading">Your Personal <span>Digital<span> Dreamcatcher</p>
        <img src="http://www.eastofthesun.com/pi7/images/dreamcatcher21.gif" class="pic">
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.heading').fadeOut(2500);
});
```

CSS(probably irrelevant):

```
@font-face{
    font-family:"Beowulf";
    src:url('C:/Users/JGSACKIN/Documents/Fonts/BEOWULF_.eot');
    src:local('BEOWULF_'), url('C:/Users/JGSACKIN/Documents/Fonts/BEOWULF_.ttf') format(truetype), url('C:/Users/JGSACKIN/Documents/Fonts/BEOWULF_.svg') format(svg);
}

.heading{
    font-family: Beowulf;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:50px;
    -webkit-opacity:1;
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
    transition: all 3s ease;
}

.pic{
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:25%;
    height:25%;
}
```

Where am I messing up here?

Comment: is "script.js" jQuery lib? I think You didn't import jQuery libs.

Comment: your span isn't closed properly <span>Digital<span> should be <span>Digital</span>

Comment: so script.js is my jquery file. Codeacademy did not make it very clear how to import jquery libs. If i'm writing in sublimetext2 do I need to take any extra steps?

Answer (score 1):

First things, I don't see where you're referencing jQuery, so let's add that. Add this line above your current `<script>` tags:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Your jQuery DOM ready function should also be in `<script>` tags:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.heading').fadeOut(2500);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you tymeJV. So I added the jQuery reference and the <script> tags around the function but am still not seeing the text fade. Only thing that changed is it takes about 5 seconds longer to load.

Comment: Note that you need to load jquery *above* your script.js, since the script you wrote *depends* on jquery in order to work. Make sure to use the javascript console for debugging